# Call different methods from different classes in a single reference in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, object, interface, reference

Having issue in Java, 
 we can call class methods like

```
interface samp{
   public void printMsg();
}
ClassA implements samp{
    public void printMsg()
    {
          S.o.p("Hi ClassA");
    }
}
ClassB implements samp{
    public void printMsg()
    {
          S.o.p("Hi ClassB");
    }
}
public MainClass{
    public static void main(String args())
    {

         samp s= new ClassA();
         s.printMsg();
         samp s= new ClassB();
         s.printMsg();
    }
}
```

we can do this, am having different type of class method not similar methods for all classes but I want to implement the future is it possible to do? is any other pattern for this, pls help me to find this.
like

```
ClassA{
    public void fun1(){..}
    public void fun2(){..}
}
ClassB{
    public void fun3(){..}
    public void fun4(){..}
}
```

want to call these methods using a single refrence, need to asign object to that refrence dynamically is it possible friends?...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain more detailed, what do you mean by `I want to implement the future` and `want to call these methods using a single refrence`?

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that using common interface.You can only call the method which is defined in interface using an interface reference type, even though the object it points to belong to another class have different other methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can call only those class function which are defined in interface because its reference can access only those functions. ex:

```
interface samp{
   public void printMsg();
}
ClassA implements samp{
    public void printMsg()
    {
          S.o.p("Hi ClassA");
    }
    public void newmthd(){
      S.o.p("you can't call me from samp reference.");
     }
}
ClassB implements samp{
    public void printMsg()
    {
          S.o.p("Hi ClassB");
    }
}
public MainClass{
    public static void main(String args())
    {

         samp s= new ClassA();
         s.printMsg();
         s.newmthd() //error... s don't have any knowledge of this function.              
         samp s= new ClassB();
         s.printMsg();

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Define all the methods you want your reference to have in an a superclass, but leave the implementations empty. Then, create your subclass and override the necessary methods.

Example:

```
Class MySuperClass {
  public void fun1() {}
  public void fun2() {}
  public void fun3() {}
  public void fun4() {}
}

Class ClassA extends MySuperClass {
  public void fun1() { //implementation details }
  public void fun2() { //implementation details }
}

Class ClassB extends MySuperClass {
  public void fun3() { //implementation details }
  public void fun4() { //implementation details }
}

public Class Tester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MySuperClass class1 = new ClassA();
    MySuperClass class2 = new ClassB();

  }
}
```

Comment: But how he can predict the future.:P  ie he says that "I want to implement the future ".

Comment: It's a little unclear what the OP wants, but I interpreted that as needing the ability to add/modify functionality to suit future needs without breaking existing code. So in this example, maybe ClassA doesn't initially override fun3, and the empty implementation is called. In the future as the project evolves it could be filled in easily.

Comment: then you are right, he forgot to define the future means in his question.